# Sql Server How to delete from multiple tables based on arbitrary array of values?

Tags: sql-server

I have an arbitrary list of values and I want to delete records across multiple tables using T-SQL. I would like to re-use the script in the future with different lists of values. This is for debugging purposes only (I just want to clear out records so they can be re-imported with the new version of the software), so it doesn't need to be pretty.

So far I have:

```
DECLARE @RequestIDList table(Request_ID nvarchar(50) NOT NULL)
INSERT INTO @RequestIDList (Request_ID) VALUES 
('00987172'), 
('01013218'), 
('01027886'), 
('01029552'), 
('01031476'), 
('01032882'), 
('01033085'), 
('01034446'), 
('01039261')
DELETE FROM Request WHERE Request_ID IN (SELECT Request_ID FROM @RequestIDList)
DELETE FROM RequestTest WHERE Request_ID IN (SELECT Request_ID FROM @RequestIDList)
```

It seems to work, but is there a better way? I can't seem to work out how to use a variable directly with an IN clause (e.g. "WHERE Request_ID IN @RequestIDList").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to create a function which parses the input

```
CREATE FUNCTION inputParser (@list nvarchar(MAX))
RETURNS @tbl TABLE (number int NOT NULL) AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @pos        int,
   @nextpos    int,
   @valuelen   int

SELECT @pos = 0, @nextpos = 1

WHILE @nextpos > 0
BEGIN
SELECT @nextpos = charindex(',', @list, @pos + 1)
SELECT @valuelen = CASE WHEN @nextpos > 0
                      THEN @nextpos
                      ELSE len(@list) + 1
                 END - @pos - 1
INSERT @tbl (number)
  VALUES (convert(int, substring(@list, @pos + 1, @valuelen)))
SELECT @pos = @nextpos
END
RETURN
END
```

Then use that function in the SP

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_delete
@RequestIDList varchar(50) 
AS
Begin
 DELETE FROM Request as req inner join 
 inputParser (@RequestIDList) i on req.Request_ID = i.number
End

EXEC usp_delete '1, 2, 3, 4'
```

For furthur details please have a look at [this](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2005.html) article .It explains differnt methods depending on the sql server version .For SQl server 2008 it uses TVP which further simplifies the input parser

Answer (score 2):

Quick script:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON

-- Temp table so it can be joined against in dynamic SQL
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#RequestIDList') IS NOT NULL 
  DROP TABLE #RequestIDList
GO

CREATE TABLE #RequestIDList (Request_ID nvarchar(50) NOT NULL)
INSERT INTO #RequestIDList (Request_ID) VALUES 
('00987172'),('01013218'),('01027886'),('01029552'), 
('01031476'),('01032882'),('01033085'),('01034446'), 
('01039261')

DECLARE @TableList TABLE (TableName NVARCHAR(128) NOT NULL) 
INSERT @TableList VALUES 
('Request'),
('RequestTest')

DECLARE 
  @sqlcmd VARCHAR(4000),
  @table  VARCHAR(128)

-- Loop through the tables in your delete list
DECLARE c CURSOR LOCAL FORWARD_ONLY STATIC READ_ONLY FOR
SELECT TableName
FROM @TableList
ORDER BY TableName

OPEN c 
FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @table
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
BEGIN 

  -- Assuming all tables in schema dbo
  -- Assuming all tables have column Request_ID
  SET @sqlcmd = 'DELETE FROM t FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@table) 
              + ' t JOIN #RequestIDList r ON r.Request_ID = t.Request_ID'

  -- PRINT @sqlcmd
  EXEC (@sqlcmd) 
  FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @table
END

CLOSE c 
DEALLOCATE c

-- Clean up
DROP TABLE #RequestIDList
```

Comment: Nice general template for this type of problem. Thanks